# php-how to move files to the folder created using userid (upload files)?

Tags: php

Need to insert uploaded file into respected folder

Here i am creating folder based on unique id.

I am not able to insert file into the folder.

when file is uploaded both file and folder are stored separately.

```
if ($file_check_error == 0){

if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$upload_directory.$path)){
echo"inside 2"."<br>";
echo"Your File Successfully Uploaded";
}
$path_user = '/home/devestctrl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.$send_id;
if (!file_exists($path_user)) {
if (mkdir( $path_user,0766,false )) {

$path_move = $path_user."/".$path;
echo $path_user;
rename($path,$path_move);
echo "Success+++++++++++";
}
else{
echo $path;
echo "Failure+++++++++++";
}   
}
}
```

$send id is unique id.

Please let me know where i have gone wrong?

Comment: You should start indent your code.. It is very hard to be followed..

Comment: @Matei Mihai ...ok sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You are messing up your logic. First you move your uploaded file

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_directory.$path)) {
```

and only than you try to create new directory

```
if (mkdir($path_user,0766,false )) {
```

and only if current user never uploaded anything you rename file moving it to other dir

```
rename($path,$path_move);
```

---

Correct logic:

1. Format uploaded file path `$path = $upload_directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$send_id`
2. Check if dir exists `file_exists($path)`
3. If not exists, create it `mkdir($path, 0766, false)`
4. Upload file `move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path)`

E.g.:

```
$path = $upload_directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$send_id;

if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0766, false);
}

move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path);
```

Comment: I know `file_exists` also checks if an directory exists, but I would use `is_dir` for readability..